# Creating Tabs in Android

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I am creating an app which has more than 5 tabs. To avoid redundancy, I want to create these tabs in a loop. However, I have difficulty in figuring out the syntax for attaching layout components to tabs in .java file. here is the code:

```
    myTabs.setup();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        TabSpec tabSpecs = myTabs.newTabSpec("tag"+i);

        tabSpecs.setContent(R.id.imageView+i); // error here

        myTabs.addTab(tabSpecs);
    }
```

This may be a silly question but I hope I will get assistance from you guys.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your problem that you use incorrect View id. You should use id only from generated R class. 
Read about [setContent method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setContent%28int%29) and try to do the next:
If you want atach different Views you need create a list of Views ID.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(R.id.R.id.imageView1);
list.add(R.id.R.id.imageView2);
list.add(R.id.R.id.imageView3);

 for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
 {
        TabSpec tabSpecs = myTabs.newTabSpec("tag"+i);
        tabSpecs.setContent(list.get(i)); 
        myTabs.addTab(tabSpecs);
 }
```

But you should define all imageViews in resource folder.
Also you can take a look on this [**example**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107693/Tabbed-Applications-in-Android).

If you look at example you will see that tab1, tab2 and tab3 - ID is defined in XML file so your IDE generate R class and include their ID in.

Comment: So if I have 24 tabs, under each tab I want to display an image, can I use one image view for all tabs.

Comment: You want to set one image for All tabs? It's mean that you will see the same content. I think it's posible, but I need to look at your XML layout to be sure. Can you update your post and add XML?